# Incompatible Pointer Type Error, sws_scale, ffmpeg

Tags: c, pointers, ffmpeg

My code is very straightforward; it consumes YUV420P data, resizes it, and produces a PNG or JPEG image (OS X Lion, Apple's gcc 4.2.1).  It works fine; I'm using ffmpeg (HEAD, as of mumble days ago), but when running in -pedantic-errors mode (which I like to do from time to time):

```c
zc_libav.c:30: error: passing argument 2 of ‘sws_scale’ from incompatible pointer type
```

Ouch!  Well, what's my code look like?

```c
sws_scale(sws_ctx, 
          in_pic->data,
          in_pic->linesize, 
          0, 
          in->y, 
          out_pic->data, 
          out_pic->linesize);
```

(You can assume for the sake of argument that the in_pic and out_pic AVPicture structures have been properly initialized, as the code *works*).

Well, what're the offending data types?

from libswscale/swscale.h:

```c
int sws_scale(struct SwsContext *c, const uint8_t* const srcSlice[], …
```

from libavcodec/avcodec.h

```c
typedef struct AVPicture {
  uint8_t *data[4];
  int linesize[4];       ///< number of bytes per line
} AVPicture;
```

As I noted above, when I change -pedantic-errors to -pedantic, I get the same complaint, but the code compiles and runs correctly.  For my own neurotic sanity, is there any way to get the advantages of -pedantic-errors and, you know, compile this code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would be ok in C++, but C doesn't have the same rules regarding const.  It doesn't like that you are passing a non-const uint8_t ** to a function that takes a const uint8_t *const *.

In C, you can convert an X * to a const X *, but it only works for one pointer level.  The next pointer level has to match exactly.

Comment: It turns out that the proper invocation was `(const uint8_t* const*)in_pic->data,`.  Thanks for the answer, though.

Comment: Thanks for sharing that, James!  I ran into this exact situation in my AVbin project (libav/ffmpeg wrapper).  One less warning to worry about now.